# problems with launching robotino_node

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've installed ROS Fuerte along with Ubuntu 12.04 for a month or so. Part of my work with ROS is to try it on our lab's robotino.

I simply want to connect my PC as a client (with a wifi stick) to Robotino as an AP to run some robotino demos provided with the stack.

But the result is always like this:

```
[ WARN] [1351922165.116894137]: The root link base_link has an inertia specified in the URDF, but KDL does not support a root link with an inertia.  As a workaround, you can add an extra dummy link to your URDF.
[ERROR] [1351922165.594054747]:
[ INFO] [1351922167.593944503]: Disconnected from Robotino
```

I also checked the connection with Robotino View and it worked to capture camera image or other sensors in Robotino View.
But it failed to run/compile robotinoView demo in Eclipse and either with ROS robotino stacks i.e robotino_node
The IP I used in robotinoView was used again to launch robotino_node

Does launching robotino_node have such trouble? and need much of debuggin or something?? I'm doubting that this relates to the compatibility between CF card v2.x and my current API2 used in ROS robotino_node.

Thank you in advance for any help!!

Cheers,
Shawn Le

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47785/problems-with-launching-robotino_node/) by [roskidos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3257/roskidos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2012-11-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is really caused by the incompatibility of CF Card v2.0 (shipped with our Robotino) with ROS. ROS uses api2 and the api I have is also api2 and they can not be used with CF Card v2.0. I tried 2 things:

- installed a CF Card v3.0 with [guide here](http://wiki.openrobotino.org/index.php?title=CF_card) but it failed. Someone's already succeeded please share some ideas
- upgrade the v2.0 CF Card with api2 with [guide here](http://wiki.openrobotino.org/index.php?title=API2_install_daemons) and it works fine (with some minor errors but can be dealed with)

Thank you!

---

Originally posted by [roskidos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3257/roskidos/) with karma: 110 on 2012-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1